How can I count a dynamically expanding firestore document in Swift?
How can I count dynamically increasing documents such as device0, device1 under devices in firebase with Swift?
I tried the code below because if I could find 1, I could get the total if I went in order until I couldn't find it, but it didn't work.(I didn't find witch one I tried but like this)
func checkDevice3Exists() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        let clientDocRef = db.collection("devices").document("device3")
                  clientDocRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                      if let document = document, document.exists {
                          let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                          print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
                          
                          if dataDescription.contains("\"device3\"") {
                              print ("field exists")
                          } else {
                                  print("field doesnt exist") }
                          } else {
                          print("Document does not exist")
                      }
                
    

and I tried these one of the below
func countDevices(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("devices").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            completion(0) 
        } else {
            let deviceCount = querySnapshot?.documents.count ?? 0
            completion(deviceCount)
        }
    }
}

// i call with below code

countDevices { deviceCount in
    print("Total:  \(deviceCount)")
}


https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation? Also: if you tried something and it didn't work, tell us what happened (and not what didn't happen). For example: was there an error message? If not, what was the output?

I tried the count function in the link you sent, but I couldn't run it in viewDidLoad because it was async.

So it's a problem that is more related to the async operation rather than the operation of counting the documents, right?

I was able to call this with the code I wrote below, but it wrote 0 in the console instead of 5.
Task {
await fetchHowManyDevices()
}

The inherent issue with the code is that as the collection scales, this .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) will return more and more documents, eventually overloading the device and crashing due to the quantity of data. The link by @puf-FrankvanPuffelen above is the correct way to get a count; use aggregation try await countQuery.getAggregation(source: .server) which works async. However, if you don't want that, store the count of documents in another collection. As documents are added/removed, increment/decrement that counter. Then read that document to reveal the count.

tried adding it to a different collection and pulling it from there, thank you

The inherent issue with the code is that as the collection scales, this
.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error)

will return more and more documents, eventually overloading the device and crashing due to the quantity of data.
The link by @puf-FrankvanPuffelen in a comment to the question is the correct solution
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#swift_1
In brief, use the count aggregation function to retrieve the count of a collection (from the docs):
let query = db.collection("cities")
let countQuery = query.count
do {
  let snapshot = try await countQuery.getAggregation(source: .server)
  print(snapshot.count)
} catch {
  print(error)
}

The above try/await works asynchronously.
However, if you don't want to use the convenient aggregate function, another option is to store the count of documents in a seperate collection.
As documents are added/removed, increment/decrement that counter. Then read that document to reveal the count.
That can be expanded on where, for example, a single collection with one document could store the count(s) of all the other collections - e.g. they are all stored in one place
count_collection
   document_counts
      users_collection: 20
      dogs_collection: 10
      cats_collection: 10

